# Is it possible to display Unity scene on Windows Forms?

Tags: winforms, unity-game-engine

I would like to know if it is possible to display Unity application over Windows Forms or if I should look for another game engine or graphics library.
My main purpose is to display next to a GUI a simple 3D scene which depends on the information of the data provided. The fact is that this is only one part of the whole project and its relevance is not enough to develop the full program on Unity.

I have seen that it is possible to create a Visual Studio Solution from Unity project but I am not sure if it is possible to import it on my project and how to communicate both of them.

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not possible or rather, not possible without maybe way too much modification that is not worth it in the end. I am not sure you understand how Unity works and I think you're confusing C# with the Unity API with the Mono framework with the .NET framework and with WinForms.

If you want to use external data to update whatever happens in Unity, you have a lot of options that actually do work natively, but WinForms is not one of them.

1. One of them and the way to do this is using the Unity GUI.
2. A second one is using built-in data that could be modified in the GUI; the built-in data could be serialized and saved onto ScriptableObjects
3. If you don't want anything at build-time and want to rely solely on runtime info, you can use data saved in files
4. If you want to rely on more than just JSON, CSV or other primitive data, you can integrate a SQLLite DB and make Unity read it
5. You can use network transfers (and either download from a website, local web server or even SaaS)
6. You can use random data that executes at runtime

But **do not** attempt to add ASP, WinForms or any other Microsoft layer over Unity. While you can use Azure, that actually counts as a SaaS so that would work.

As for using C# Microsoft-only technology in Unity, trust me, the effort into building something that can work is not worth it. And yes, you might say "well, it's still C#, isn't it?" that's like saying you can "write" a Windows app to work under Linux because "it's still C, isn't it?".